# Magento 2: Run code in external file/script

Tags: magento, magento2

How can I run magento code from external file.

Is it possible to execute magento code in external file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

/**
 * If your external file is in root folder
 */
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

/**
 * If your external file is NOT in root folder
 * Let's suppose, your file is inside a folder named 'xyz'
 *
 * And, let's suppose, your root directory path is
 * /var/www/html/magento2
 */
// $rootDirectoryPath = '/var/www/html/magento2';
// require $rootDirectoryPath . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$quoteId = 1;
$quote = $obj->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')
             ->getQuote()
             ->load($quoteId);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($quote->getOrigData());
echo '</pre>';

$productId = 1;
$product = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')
               ->getById($productId);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($product->getData());
echo '</pre>';
?>
```